# send binary on node.JS serial

Tags: node.js

I'm using SerialPort https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport in a node.JS test script. I need to write the following sequence:

```
"\xc0\x00--EOF-Pattern--"
```

The device behind the Serial port expects the bytes to transmit and then the EOF pattern to show the end of the payload. A number of other binary send works fine.

However when I try to send "0xC0" it always ends in sending crap bytes. It looks that my hex is always somewhere translated into Unicode (or something similar).

Even when I do something like

```
var buff = Buffer.from("c0002d2d454f462d2d5061747465726e2d2d","hex");
```

and send "buff" to the SerialPort the Hex sequence is destroyed. Again - this only happens when a "0xC0" is in.

Any hint what I can do ? How to prevent ANY recoding on the serial line API ?

Comment: It *should* be sending the bytes as you've defined. Have you verified, e.g., by sniffing the serial line, that it's the wrong data on the wire, and there isn't an issue on the receiving side? Or by sending the same byte sequence via a different serial mechanism? Is it an issue only when `0xC0` is the *first* byte? It may also be helpful to provide some context, e.g., the `open` and `write` at least.

Comment: Hello thanks for your comment. This was clear case of not seeing the tree for the forest. Your comment lead me to review very cleanly (not that I did that before for hours) every line and I realized that was adding somewhere a line delimiter. I fixed that and it works. Thanks again - sometimes we need to be punched with the head against it ...

Comment: Glad you worked it out :) I've spent a lot of time debugging serial protocol issues and I've found it's almost always my fault ;)